# In a nested TS based Vite + Vue3 project I can "build" but cannot "dev"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, commonjs, monorepo

I have a nested TS project with Vue3 + Vite living in a subdirectory directly under the project's root. That Vue3 project imports types and consts from `src` of the root project. I managed the types import to work by building the root project with `yarn tsc -d` (to generate and dump `*.d.ts` files into `dist` and import types from there).

But I cannot do that same trick with variables exported as const. My best result (adjusting `vite.config.ts` to use `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` plugin) was to make `yarn build` work and produce a correct build, but I cannot make `yarn dev` to work.

Here is the error message

```
yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vite

  VITE v4.1.1  ready in 263 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
Failed to resolve import "commonjsHelpers.js" from "../dist/types.js". Does the file exist?
6:20:17 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "commonjsHelpers.js" from "../dist/types.js". Does the file exist?
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/dist/types.js:1:35
  1  |  import * as commonjsHelpers from "commonjsHelpers.js";
     |                                    ^
  2  |  import { __exports as types } from "\u0000/Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/dist/types.js?commonjs-exports"
  3  |  
      at formatError (file:///Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/ui2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:41389:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/ui2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:41385:19)
      at normalizeUrl (file:///Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/ui2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:39693:33)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/ui2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:39826:47)
      at async Object.transform (file:///Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/ui2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:41660:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///Users/simon/Projects/ts-test/ui2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:39466:29)
```

I created a repo for demonstration purposes and added all details into README file https://github.com/servernoj/ts-test/blob/main/README.md